# Sorting a GridView's column containing HyperLinks

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, hyperlink

I am making a project in aspx.net and I have a GridView with several columns filled with text. I am trying to modify the first column as it has to contain the case number of the information displayed in the row, as an HyperLink. The problem I have is that when I add the HyperLink class object, it does not sort the column anymore, as the values in the column stay in the same possition, while the other fields of the row do actually move.

```
HyperLinko = New HyperLink()
HyperLinko.NavigateUrl = "VentanaExpediente.aspx?sesionid=" & SesionID & "&empleado=" & EmpleadoInicial & "&expediente=" & ValorCampo
HyperLinko.Text = ValorCampo
GridViewDatos.Rows(X).Cells(Y).Controls.Add(HyperLinko)
```

I have tried displaying the link as an html link and formating it, but without any improvement.

```
Dim Hipervinculo As String
Hipervinculo = "<a href='VentanaExpediente.aspx?sesionid=" & SesionID & "&empleado=" & EmpleadoInicial & "&expediente=" & ValorCampo & "'>" & ValorCampo & "</a>"
   GridViewDatos.Rows(X).Cells(Y).Text = Hipervinculo
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?